# How to output the results of a stored procedure with a while loop MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm performing some calculations on tsunami's wave time between different radii. I'm having trouble outputting the results of the stored procedure into a table. The output I get is a blank table without any data stored. The log says "0 rows affected". For some reason my inputs and outputs are not registering. I thinking it could have something to do with the way I'm using the loop inside to SP.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Tsunami
(
    @oceanDepth int,
    @radii1 int,
    @radii2 int,
    @tsunamiSpeed int OUTPUT,
    @tsunamiTimeDifference int OUTPUT
)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET @tsunamiSpeed = sqrt(32.1725 * @oceanDepth) * (60.0/88.0);
        Truncate Table dbo.Tsunami

        DECLARE @i int
            SET @i = 0;
            WHILE (@i <= 10000)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.Tsunami (Radius, Wavetime)
                VALUES
                    (@i, (@i / @tsunamiSpeed))
                SET @i = @i + 100;  
            END         

        DECLARE @tsunamiTime1 int
        DECLARE @tsunamiTime2 int
        SET @tsunamiTime1 = (Select Wavetime From Tsunami WHERE Radius = @radii1);
        SET @tsunamiTime2 = (Select Wavetime From Tsunami WHERE Radius = @radii2);
        SET @tsunamiTimeDifference = (@tsunamiTime2 - @tsunamiTime1);   
    END

    /* Outputs */
    DECLARE @Out_tsunamiSpeed int
    DECLARE @Out_tsunamiTimeDifference int


    /* Inputs */
    DECLARE @IN_oceanDepth int
    DECLARE @IN_radii1 int
    DECLARE @IN_radii2 int
    SET @IN_oceanDepth = 15088; 
    SET @IN_radii1 = 2500; 
    SET @IN_radii2 = 7500;

    Execute SP_Tsunami @oceanDepth = @IN_oceanDepth, @radii1 = @IN_radii1, @radii2 = @IN_radii2, @tsunamiSpeed = @Out_tsunamiSpeed OUTPUT, @tsunamiTimeDifference = @Out_tsunamiTimeDifference OUTPUT
```

Comment: Isn't `@tsunamiTimeDifference = (@radii2 - @radii1)/(@k * sqrt(@oceanDepth))`, with `@k = (60.0/88.0) * sqrt(32.1725)`?  Do you really need the table?

Comment: Would you mind adding sample data from your dbo.Tsunami table? Or even better if you could create a SQL Fiddle example.

Comment: I'm going to be printing the output for @tsunamiTimeDifference,  not insert it in a table. I want the loop to create and insert data into the table, and the other function performs a separate calculation which I will output via Print.

Comment: @Anon I wont need a table for that. That is a side calculation. I'm going to print the output for tsunamiTimeDifference. I want the loop to create and insert data into the table. Specifically 101 rows of data which contains radii and wavetime values.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't make much sense to insert the data into table and then read it from there. All the rows you are inserting into your table eventually only one row is being read from the table to assign values to variables.

Also change the procedure name prefix from `sp_` to something else, `sp_` is system stored procedure prefix.

I have changed the procedure definition a little bit hope it makes sense.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_Tsunami
(
    @oceanDepth int,
    @radii1 int,
    @radii2 int,
    @tsunamiSpeed int OUTPUT,
    @tsunamiTimeDifference int OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @tsunamiSpeed = sqrt(32.1725 * @oceanDepth) * (60.0/88.0);


    DECLARE @tsunamiTime1 int
    DECLARE @tsunamiTime2 int

    SET @tsunamiTime1 = @radii1 / @tsunamiSpeed;
    SET @tsunamiTime2 = @radii2 / @tsunamiSpeed;

    SET @tsunamiTimeDifference = (@tsunamiTime2 - @tsunamiTime1);   
END
GO
```

Execute the procedure with your provided data.

```
/* Outputs */
DECLARE @Out_tsunamiSpeed int
DECLARE @Out_tsunamiTimeDifference int


/* Inputs */
DECLARE @IN_oceanDepth int
DECLARE @IN_radii1 int
DECLARE @IN_radii2 int
SET @IN_oceanDepth = 15088; 
SET @IN_radii1 = 2500; 
SET @IN_radii2 = 7500;

Execute SP_Tsunami @oceanDepth = @IN_oceanDepth
                 , @radii1 = @IN_radii1
                 , @radii2 = @IN_radii2
                 , @tsunamiSpeed = @Out_tsunamiSpeed OUTPUT
                 , @tsunamiTimeDifference = @Out_tsunamiTimeDifference OUTPUT

SELECT @Out_tsunamiSpeed AS Out_tsunamiSpeed
      ,@Out_tsunamiTimeDifference AS Out_tsunamiTimeDifference
```

### Result Set:

```
Out_tsunamiSpeed    Out_tsunamiTimeDifference
     475                         10
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits. It wasn't quite what I had in mind but this is useful too. What I'm trying to do is have 101 rows insert via the loop. The table will have two columns (Radius, Wavetime). This way I can see the different tsunami Radii with its corresponding wavetime. I have this accomplished using a non-procedural method, but unable to do this same with an SP.